# Alert for mobile users to switch to desktop should show only once but keeps repeating

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, mobile, alert

I am trying to alert users of my web-application to switch to desktop for optimal experience. The alert box should only appear once, but so far it keeps popping up with every refresh or reload of the page.

```
<script language="Javascript">
    window.onload=function(){
    var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
    if (mobile) {
         var alerted = localStorage.getItem('alerted') || '';
        if (alerted != 'yes') {
         alert("Visit this on a Computer for Better View");
         localStorage.setItem('alerted','yes');

    } else {

    }}}
</script>
```

Any tips what is missing for the item to be recalled?

Thanks

Alex

Comment: The best tip is just to not do this.  If your website looks bad on mobile, your users are going to know that your website looks bad on mobile.  Annoying them with this information in an aggressive `alert()` box isn't going to help with this issue.  Also, user-agent sniffing is a particularly bad way to determine feature support and display information.  There are plenty of desktop-like Android devices, for example.

Comment: Thanks, I see that point - just in my case a lot of the functionality is missing without a mouse, but it is not obvious through the mobile interface what you are missing out on

Comment: There are plenty of desktop browsers that don't have mice, and there are mobile devices that do.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 <script language="Javascript">
  window.onload=function(){
  var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
  if (mobile) {
     var alerted = localStorage.getItem('alerted') || false;
    if (alerted !== true) {
     alert("Visit this on a Computer for Better View");
     localStorage.setItem('alerted', true);
   } else {
     ...
   }}}
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I get the same result - with every refresh the alert shows again